# In SQLite3, how do I troubleshoot a "Error: UNIQUE constraint failed" from an "insert into select"?

Tags: sql, sqlite, primary-key, unique-constraint

When I get a `Error: UNIQUE constraint failed`, is there a way to see which **value** caused the unique constraint violation? [I have evidence that other databases tell you this information](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130108/postgresql-unique-constraint-error-message) (see the DETAIL line in the question), but after an hour+ of research, I can't find if SQLite3 can do this. If it can, how do you enable this feature?

BTW, [I'm not looking for workarounds like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45299979/61624), I want to learn how to troubleshoot this.

I am using the sqlite3 commandline client.

Comment: It might have taken you over an hour to troubleshoot this but only because this is, presumably, the first time you’ve seen this type of error? Next time it shouldn’t take you more than a couple of minutes to identify the problem records. Even if the error showed you the data that caused the error it would only be the first record that caused the error, you wouldn’t know if there were other records that would cause the error. That’s why you write queries to check your data and, having done it once, the next time should be easy

Comment: It depends on if there are items already on the table, but I would generally write a quick row_number() with the partition being the key. Then write a select around that where row number is greater then 1. https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-row_number/ would get a good head start.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. This post is rambling & unclear. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Paraphrase or quote from other text with credit, give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: @philipxy I've edited my question. Let me know if an issue remains.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SQLite's [upsert syntax](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) to find these colliding values.

Try something like this, maybe?

```sql
insert into a_table (id1, id2)
select  ... whatever ...
  ON CONFLICT() DO UPDATE 
         SET id1=excluded.id1 || '-dup' || RANDOM,
         SET id2=excluded.id2 || '-dup' || RANDOM;
```

(Not sure I have the syntax exactly right.) This will tag your duplicate values with `-dup123456` like tags. This only works if `id1` and `id2` are text.

But, if these are your only two columns and together their values are the PK, you can simply ignore the issue by saying `ON CONFLICT() DO NOTHING`. If your application's integrity won't suffer by ignoring those dups.

This syntax was added to SQLite with version 3.24.0 (2018-06-04).

**Edit** you can run a separate SELECT to detect the collisions before you attempt the update. Maybe something like this will help. Note my use of the [WITH common table expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) as a way to make the query clearer.

```sql
WITH newkeys AS (
 select d_table.id1,
        '1' as id2
   from b_table
   join c_table on b_table.id = c_table.path_id
   join d_table on c_table.id = d_table.id1
   left join a_table on d_table.id1 = a_table.id1
  where a_table.id1 is null
    and b_table.path like 'X:\%'
)
SELECT COUNT(*) number_of_duplicates_in_a_table,
       a_table.id1, a_table.id2
  FROM a_table
  JOIN newkeys  
            ON a_table.id1 = newkeys.id1
           AND b_table.id2 = newkeys.id2
 GROUP BY a_table.id1, a_table.id2
```

Comment: This (the `on conflict() do update`) is a clever idea, but I'm assuming it wouldn't work if there is a foreign key for these ids? Or does this ignore all constraints, including foreign keys? The `ON CONFLICT() DO NOTHING` feels like a workaround though?

Comment: You're right about foreign key constraints messing up my nasty `on conflict() do update` hack. See my edit.

Comment: Apologies, but per a suggestion, I heavily updated my question to the point that this answer now appears off topic. It did help me though. +1

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if there are items already on the table, but I would generally write a quick row_number() with the partition being the key. Then write a select around that where row number is greater then 1. https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-row_number/ would get a good head start.

This will be incorrect because I am not working with an entire set, but:

```
select * from
(
select d_table.id1,
    '1' as id2,
    row_number() over ( partition by d_table.id1, '1' order by d_table.id1) as rowNum
from b_table
    join c_table on b_table.id = c_table.path_id
    join d_table on c_table.id = d_table.id1
    left join a_table on d_table.id1 = a_table.id1
where a_table.id1 is null
    and b_table.path like 'X:\%'
) d where d.rowNum > 1
order by 1;
```

This gives you row numbers, then the other select only cares about those items that have more then one matching row.

**Edited**

For the edit / comment below.

```
select *
from
(
    select *, 
    row_number() over ( partition by d.id1, d.id2 order by  d_table.id1) as rowNum from
    (
      select * from a_tableid
      union all 
      select d_table.id1,
         '1' as id2
      from b_table
        join c_table on b_table.id = c_table.path_id
        join d_table on c_table.id = d_table.id1
        left join a_table on d_table.id1 = a_table.id1
      where a_table.id1 is null
        and b_table.path like 'X:\%'
    ) d 
) e where e.rowNum > 1
order by 1;
```

Really messy, but will be a dirty way to find the duplicates.

Comment: I have updated my question to state that `a_table` was already populated before the `insert`.

Comment: @DanielKaplan then you union the tables. So, select * from table a, union all the select statement, then do a row over on the outer part of that, and then a select where rowNum is greater then 1 over that.

Comment: Apologies, but per a suggestion, I heavily updated my question to the point that this answer now appears off topic. It did help me though. +1